# UILabel adjust its frame to text length

Tags: ios

Is it possible that my UILabel adjusts its frame size to the length of the text of the UILabel?? If yes, how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `-sizeToFit`:

```
[label sizeToFit];
```

And what's more, you can also adjust the font size to fit width:

```
[label setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:YES];
[label setMinimumFontSize:8.f];
```